# Motor driver shield l239D should be giving enough power but it doesn't

Tags: arduino-uno, power, arduino-motor-shield

I am doing a line follower robot using motor driver shield l239D stacked with an Arduino uno to run 2 DC motors and two infrared sensors. I am supplying 12V to the motor driver shield trough three 18650 batteries. 
The point is the car was working fine and it followed the line but  two days ago it stopped working after one week of working fine...
When the two DC motors and two sensors are connected the motors don't move they just buzz(the sound it makes when it's not getting enough power), it works sometimes a little bit...

Basically the car only works with no sensor connected. So I made measurements with the multimeter and I got this:

The three batteries:12.62V

The shield receives: 12.39V only with the two sensors connected and the motors disconnected.

The shield with the motors and two sensors connected:12.28V.

And when I measured how much the motors where receiving I got 0V! In both of them...

With just one motor and the sensors connected the motor started buzzing and I got 0.07V till the sound stopped and I got zero again.

Sometimes the motors work a little bit sometimes they just buzz and some times they don't buzz at all...

I see that the batteries are fine and they can deliver enough current for everything to work but the motors don't receive almost anything!!!

Can you help me and tell me suggestions of what I need to do please? I searched and asked a lot but haven't found anything that helps...
Here is my car and my circuit.

[image][image][image]

Comment: If you are working  with dupont plugs check each of them sounds like a problem with connection - check for loose/not fully connecting plugs and pins. Because if it worked the only other solution is you fried something by overheating/overpowering

Comment: If it is "only works with no sensor connected", then it is something to do with your code. Edit your post and add your code.

Comment: The cause is really the lack of power because with one sensor it works. But could it be because my wires for the batteries are thin? Wich doesn't make sense because they can passe the 12V to the shield... But could it be from it?

Comment: Does the motors work with the sensors disconnected? Do the sensors work with the motors disconnected? Did you measure the voltage at the output terminals of the shield as well as the input? If you can isolate the fault to one component it would be a lot easier to fix.